# I have trouble understanding a GZipStream ASP.Net Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gzipstream

I consider myself pretty good in C#, but I am facing trouble in understanding the following piece of code:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var responseStream = httpContext.Response.Body;
    httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream;

    await this.next(httpContext);

    using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new [] { "gzip" });
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(compressedStream);
    }
}
```

This code is extracted from an ASP.Net Core middleware that compresses the HTTP response, and "surprisingly", it works... or so it seems (I tested it with Fiddler).

Let me put my understanding first:

- The code starts with taking a reference to `httpContext.Response.Body` in `responseStream`.
- Then it replaces `httpContext.Response.Body` reference with the newly initialised `memoryStream`.
- If my understanding of how C# references work, I say we still have a reference to the original `httpContext.Response.Body` data with `responseStream`, while `httpContext.Response.Body` new data is empty.
- Next, we are calling the next middleware in the pipeline.
- Because `this.next()` is awaitable, our code execution will "stop" until all middlewares return.
- When our code execution "resumes", it will initialise a `GZipStream`, adds a response header, and "seeks" to the beginning of `memoryStream`.
- Finally, it copies the content or `memoryStream` to `compressedStream`, which writes it to `responseStream`.

So, what is the relation between `memoryStream`, `compressedStream`, and `responseStream`? We created `compressedStream` to write to `responseStream` and then eventually to `httpContext.Response.Body`, but the reference from `responseStream` to `httpContext.Response.Body` isn't there anymore?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW the OOB [`ResponseCompressionMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/ResponseCompressionMiddleware.cs#L59) looks a bit different nowadays.

But in the sample you pasted, i'll annotate to illustrate why `memoryStream` is NOT actually empty by the time it gets copied to `compressedStream`.

```cs
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) // Create a buffer so we can capture response content written by future middleware/controller actions
{
    var responseStream = httpContext.Response.Body; // save a reference to the ACTUAL STREAM THAT WRITES TO THE HTTP RESPONSE WHEN WRITTEN TO.
    httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream; // replace HttpContext.Response.Body with our buffer (memoryStream).

    await this.next(httpContext); // <== somewhere in here is where HttpContext.Response.Body gets written to, and since Body now points to memoryStream, really memoryStream gets written to.

    using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)) // Here is where we wrap the ACTUAL HTTP RESPONSE STREAM with our ready-to-write-to compressedStream.
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new [] { "gzip" });
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Previously, we set HttpContext.Response.Body to a memoryStream buffer, then SOMEONE in the middleware chain or controller action wrote to that Body, we can seek to the beginning of what they wrote, and copy that content to the compressedStream.
        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(compressedStream);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code simply takes what the next middleware in the pipeline has written to the `memoryStream` object and compresses it for responding back to the client with whatever was in the `responseStream` before this piece of middleware ran.

So existing `responseStream` content + `memoryStream` content.

Comment: If it was as simple as that; I wouldn't have asked ;) `httpContext.Response.Body` is what's returned to the client; in what part of the code I'm writing anything to it, except assigning `responseStream` that does not have any content.

Comment: These two statements:
`var responseStream = httpContext.Response.Body;` and
`new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)`

Comment: This exactly what confuses me :| the code initialises `responseStream` to "point to" `httpContext.Response.Body`; however, `httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream;` part removed that reference, and now `httpContext.Response.Body` is something else... or is there something in .Net references I'm missing here?

Comment: The code you refer to just reassigns the pointers, it doesn't change the values.

Comment: It seem like this is a stupid question for you and you may think "how come you can't get it?" You're trying to answer the question without pointing to the part(s) I misunderstood and confused about. Yes `responseStream` contains the initial `httpContext.Response.Body` and `compressedStream` is it's compressed version. Now we're taking `memoryStream` which is empty (it's just initialised) and writing it's content (empty) to `compressedStream`. Which part of this understanding is wrong and why?